# Showing subcategory articles under headings for blog layout

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

We are setting up a custom blog layout override for a Joomla site. I am trying to display the sub categories articles under their category headings.

For example the following structure:
Main Cat
  - Sub Cat
   --  Article 1
   --  Article 2
   - Sub Cat
   --  Article 3

This layout is how the articles should display on the main blog override. For example going to Main Cat would display the above layout.

The subcategories are included in the default way with the following:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->children[$this->category->id]) && $this->maxLevel != 0) : ?>
    <div class="cat-children">
        <?php if ($this->params->get('show_category_heading_title_text', 1) == 1) : ?>
            <h3> <?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SUBCATEGORIES'); ?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $this->loadTemplate('children'); ?> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In the child override the title is included then we would like to display the articles from that child category.

I have tried multiple different versions of getting a `for each` to work for the sub articles but cannot get it to work.
For example:

```
    <?php foreach ($this->child->children[$child->id] as $key => $item) : ?>
        1
        <?php echo $item->title; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Are you positive you have the data? What do you need to do to dump out one record?

Comment: Yes. If the category is empty it wouldn't output the title. I just can't get the access/loop to the children to work

Comment: Well not showing the title is because the title display is inside that if, why not just move that out?

Comment: The title is within a empty check on children. Move what out?

Comment: So actually let's start over. The code you showed is simply saying if there are any child categories load the child template. Agree?  Now what is the code in the child template that you are attempting to override?  By the way I think you would be better served by using the CategorIES layout which has display of the items in child categories built in as an option.

Comment: What is the menu option for categories. I selected blog menu type originally. But following on from above correct. The code at the bottom of my question is what I'm adding to the children override file within the sub category loop. At the moment that only shows some basic sub category information like title. But I want it to loop through the articles in the child category too

Comment: The menu option is Categories. (Note the plural)

Comment: The 'List all categories' item under Articles??

Comment: Yes, it has a million options and you can get the sub category articles.